# If statement inside Wordpress Contact Form 7 E-mail area

Tags: conditional-statements

I want to send myself an email with the figure 600 in the email message but have it change to 400 if a user checks a box that says Guest A or Guest B. Is there a way to do that?

Form:

```
<p><label for="na"><b>Na (<span class="red">Required</span>)</b> </label>[radio na id:na class:na use_label_element default:0 default:get "Guest A" "Guest B"] </p>
```